# Install on Acer Aspire One D255E

Tags: 10.10, installation, ubuntu-netbook

When I try to install via USB all I see is a cursor at the top of the screen after a brief flash that show Linux being initialized.  The system just hangs.  This happened when I tried Lubuntu as well.  Any ideas how to install on my brick?

Comment: Have you tried to disable graphical boot to see what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I installed Ubuntu Desktop Edition on my Acer Aspire One and it works perfectly. I also got in troubles with the USB image but I did another one image and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that instead of installing the netbook version you should install the full desktop edition of 10.10 (32-bit).  I've done that on my newer HP Mini netbooks, and it works perfectly (also done this with slightly older Acer netbooks in the 1.5 - 2 year old age range).

Answer (score 0):

On some Aspire netbooks you need to enable you need to turn on network boot in the BIOS.
 [See more here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne722#Booting_USB_media)